Comparing sum of two largest roots of two polynomials
There is an interesting lemma that I have found at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379523003294. This claims that we can compare the largest roots of two polynomials given that both polynomials are monic, of the same degree, and all roots are real. One of the sufficient conditions given is that $g(t) - f(t) \geq 0,$ where $t_1$ is the largest root of $g(t)$ which guarantees that $t_1 \leq t_2$ where $t_2$ is the largest root of $f(t).$
Now, I am wondering if we can also compare the sum of the two largest roots of two polynomials with the same conditions, i.e., if $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are polynomials which are monic, of the same degree, and all roots are real, and that $a$ and $b$ are the two largest roots of $f(t)$ while $c$ and $d$ are the two largest roots of $g(t),$ is it possible to determine whether which sum is larger: $a+b$ or $c+d$ without computing the roots of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ at all?
For example, consider $f(t) = t^5 - a_1t^3 + a_2t - a_3$ and
$g(t) = t^5 - b_1t^3 + b_2t - b_3$ where $a_i, b_i \geq 0$ for all $i=1,2,3.$ Descartes' rule of signs asserts that both of these polynomials have five real roots. However, I am not sure if their roots can be expressed by radicals or by Bring radicals so I was thinking if we can invoke a condition similar to the one in the beginning to say that $f(t)$ (or $g(t)$) has larger sum of its two largest roots than that of $g(t)$ (or $f(t)$).
Any help/hint would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much!

I think you had best give an example problem  with actual numbers

Easy case: if f(t) and g(t) are both second degree polynomials of the form $ax^2 +bx + c$ then the sum of the roots is -b/a, which gives us an easy way to check
